# Switch case menu

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that prompts the user a menu of options  like this

```
*****************************************************************
Enter the number corresponding to the desired pay rate or action:
1) $8.75/hr 2) $9.33/hr
3) $10.00/hr 4) $11.20/hr
5) quit
*****************************************************************
```

And then calculate the net pay, gross pay and tax, according to the pay rate. I have all the pay rates done but the actual menu of rates is giving me problems.If the user enter 5 it should quit and if enters anything other and 1 through 5 then recycle and ask again for proper choice. I have a problem recycling if input is any other than 1 through 5.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "ctype.h"
#define HOURLY0   8.75
#define HOURLY1  9.33
#define HOURLY2  10
#define HOURLY3  11.20
#define TAXRATE  .15
#define TAXRATE2 .20
#define TAXRATE3 .25
#define OVERTIME 15


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float hours, grossPay = 0, netPay, tax = 0, tax3 = 0,hourly;
    int menu = 0,wrong =1;
    char quit;

    printf("Enter the number corresponding to the desired pay rate or action : \n\n1) $8.75/hr          2) $9.33/hr \n3) $10.00/hr         4) $11.20/hr \n5) quit\n\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &menu);
        while (menu != 5 )
        {
            do
            {
                switch (menu)
                {
                case 1:
                    hourly = HOURLY0;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    hourly = HOURLY1;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    hourly = HOURLY2;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    hourly = HOURLY3;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Enter right choice from 1 to 5 only\n");
                    printf("Enter the number corresponding to the desired pay rate or action : \n\n1) $8.75/hr          2) $9.33/hr \n3) $10.00/hr         4) $11.20/hr \n5) quit\n\n");
                    scanf_s("%d", &menu);
                    wrong;
                    break;
                }
            } while (!wrong);/* HOW CAN I MAKE IT TO RECYCLE IF INPUT IS OTHER THAN 1-5*/
            printf("\nEnter hours worked in the week: ");
            scanf_s("%f", &hours);

            if (hours > 40)
            {
                grossPay = (40 * hourly) + ((hours - 40) * OVERTIME);

                if (grossPay <= 300)
                {
                    tax = grossPay * TAXRATE;
                }
                if (grossPay > 300 && grossPay < 450)
                {
                    tax = (300 * TAXRATE) + ((grossPay - 300)*TAXRATE2);
                }
                if (grossPay > 450)
                {
                    tax3 = grossPay - 450;
                    tax = (300 * TAXRATE) + ((grossPay - 300 - tax3)*TAXRATE2) + ((grossPay - 300 - 150)*TAXRATE3);
                }

            }
            else if (hours < 40)
            {
                grossPay = (hours * hourly);

                if (grossPay <= 300)
                {
                    tax = grossPay * TAXRATE;
                }

                if (grossPay > 300 && grossPay < 450)
                {
                    tax = (300 * TAXRATE) + ((grossPay - 300)*TAXRATE2);
                }
                if (grossPay > 450)
                {
                    tax3 = grossPay - 450;
                    tax = (300 * TAXRATE) + ((grossPay - 300 - tax3)*TAXRATE2) + ((grossPay - 300 - 150)*TAXRATE3);
                }
            }
            netPay = grossPay - tax;
            printf("\nGross Pay : %2.3f\nTax: %13.3f\nNet Pay: %10.3f\n\n", grossPay, tax, netPay);
            system("cls");
            printf("Enter the number corresponding to the desired pay rate or action : \n\n1) $8.75/hr          2) $9.33/hr \n3) $10.00/hr         4) $11.20/hr \n5) quit\n\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &menu);
        }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you never set the value of `wrong` to 0, so the loop `while(!wrong)` should probably never exit. You would be better off using a `bool` for `wrong` instead of an `int` and you should set it to `false` for cases 1 through 5, and `true` for the default case.

Comment: @YoungJohn in C even boolean is actually a char.

Comment: you are absolutely right, for some reason I thought this was tagged with C++

Answer (score 2):

One way to improve the code is to move user input processing into a subroutine. That way, all of the messy error handling goes into the subroutine and `main` only has to process valid inputs.

In the code below, the `GetUserInput` function will loop forever, until either the user enters a valid number, or an end-of-file or error occurs in the `scanf`. The return value from `GetUserInput` can *only* be a value from 1 thru 5, so `main` doesn't need to handle any unexpected values.

```
int GetUserInput( void )
{
    int menu;

    for (;;)
    {
        menu = 0;
        printf("Enter the number corresponding to the desired pay rate or action : \n\n1) $8.75/hr          2) $9.33/hr \n3) $10.00/hr         4) $11.20/hr \n5) quit\n\n");
        if ( scanf( "%d", &menu ) != 1 )
            exit( 1 );

        if ( menu >= 1 && menu <= 5 )
            return menu;

        printf( "Enter right choice from 1 to 5 only\n" );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int menu = 0;

    while ( menu != 5 )
    {
        menu = GetUserInput();
        switch ( menu )
        {
            case 1:  printf( "\n*** You selected 1 ***\n\n" ); break;
            case 2:  printf( "\n*** You selected 2 ***\n\n" ); break;
            case 3:  printf( "\n*** You selected 3 ***\n\n" ); break;
            case 4:  printf( "\n*** You selected 4 ***\n\n" ); break;
            case 5:  printf( "Bye\n" ); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `scanf()` you need to be aware of that when a user enters a value scanf tries to read out only what you write in the format specifier, the rest still remains in the buffer. So writing "%d" means it reads the number but left in the buffer is \n.

Now when you later do another scanf the \n is still in the buffer so scanf directly returns 0.

Instead use `fgets()` to read the value from the keyboard into a character string, then use `sscanf()` or `atoi()` to retrieve the integer.

e.g.

```
char buffer[256];
while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin)!=NULL)
{
  if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n) == 1)
  {
    switch(n) {...}
  }
  else
  {
    ... some error output ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the **while(!wrong)** loop, were you have put your comment, add:

```
if(wrong)
    continue; //restart from the outer-while
```

and initiate **wrong=0** at the begining and set it to **1** at the **default** choice of **switch**.